# could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: postgresql, ssl, psql, redash

We are using a Redash AMI hosted on an ec2 instance, and suddenly while executing a query our instance got crashed, After rebooting the instance the Redash server was up and running but now while running queries we started getting this `could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable` error.

We tried connecting the database from the instance using `psql` command but it is also not working.

We have checked the security groups of the RDS - PSQL, it already have the IP whitelisted of redash instance.

It would be great if someone can help us in fixing the problem.

Comment: Probably just crash recovery. Wait a while. Look at the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved. I had to whitelist the private IP of the Redash instance to the rds security group.